# Large file to base64 string array

Tags: java, android, string, base64, arrays

My function returns a string which is out of its limit, because of the large file size I am using.

Is there a way to create a function that returns a string array so that later on I can cascade them and recreate the file ?

```
private String ConvertVideoToBase64()
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    FileInputStream fis;

    try {
        File inputFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Videos/out.mp4");

        fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n;
        while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
            baos.write(buf, 0, n);
        byte[] videoBytes = baos.toByteArray();

        fis.close();

        return Base64.encodeToString(videoBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        //imageString = videoString;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The entire movie probably dooesn't fit in RAM at once, which is what you are trying to do with your `baos` object.

Try rewriting your code in such a way as to encode each 1024-byte chunk, and then write to a file / send over the network / whatever.

Edit: I think you need to use a streaming approach. This is common on platforms where you can't / don't want to hold all the data in memory at once.

The basic algorithm will be:

```
Open your file. This is an input stream.
Connect to your server. This is your output stream

While the file has data
 Read some amount of bytes, say 1024, from the file into a buffer.
 encode these bytes into a Base64 string
 write the string to the server

Close server connection
Close file
```

You have the input stream side. I'll presume you have some web service you are POSTing to. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html to get started with the output stream.

Comment: How can I write a file into 1024-byte chunks ? Also, lets say I write the file into 1024 byte chunks, I also need to convert every chunk into base-64 and add them to gather on the server side right ?

Comment: +1 for your nice answer :) Yes I am posting base64 data to a web service, but I am making a call by sending the total string to it at once. Therefore I would prefer using a parameter (let say mediaString[]) if it is possible. What you recommend is like syncing data to a web service, I would prefer do that afterwards I obtain the mediaString[].